# Capture and alter QNetworkRequests sended from the application

Tags: qt, networking, qml, media-player

I heed to amend a request header to some of my HTTP requests which application sends, but they managed by QML [`MediaPlayer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html). I tried to use [`setNetworkAccessManagerFactory()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#setNetworkAccessManagerFactory), like it shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487703/qt-mediaplayer-send-additional-http-headers-in-source-urls-in-qml), and it works with [`Image`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html), but it still does not work with [`MediaPlayer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html). Apperantely, [`MediaPlayer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html) does not using [`QNetworkAccessManager`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html).

How can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507317/how-do-i-play-a-stream-with-qmediaplayer - it should put you one step closer. i.e. by being able to declare a custom stream, you can link your QNetworkAccessManager with custom headers to the media stream.

Comment: @StephenQuan, thanks for your advice, but VLC-Qt is a desktop-only library, my application should have to support iOS and Android.

Comment: I mean for you to look at how they add a custom backend. As a matter of fact, try searching for other answers that involve in QMediaPlayer but with either (1) a custom url scheme, or (2) a custom QIODevice.